# react-router-dom with react hooks not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

My app.js Component

```
import React, { lazy, Suspense } from 'react'
import './App.css'
// import io from 'socket.io-client'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'

//lazy load the components
const Login = lazy(() => import('./Components/Login/Login'))
const Home = lazy(() => import('./Components/Home/Home'))
const List = lazy(() => import('./Components/List/List'))
const Page404 = lazy(() => import('./Components/404/'))

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className='App'>
        <Suspense
          fallback={
            <div
              style={{
                display: 'flex',
                justifyContent: 'center',
                alignItems: 'center',
                height: '100vh',
                fontFamily: "'Ubuntu', sans-serif",
                fontSize: '30px'
              }}
            >
              Loading..
            </div>
          }
        >
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/'>
              <Home />
            </Route>
            <Route path='/create_user_name'>
              <Login />
            </Route>
            <Route path='/list'>
              <List />
            </Route>
            <Route component={Page404} />
          </Switch>
        </Suspense>
      </div>
    </Router>
  )
}

export default App
```

When I try to use `history.push('/list')`,  the URL of my page is changing but content of the page is not changed.

Example:
When I go to `/create_user_name` and click a button `history.push('/list')` is executed.
The URL of the page changed from **/create_user_name** to **/list** but the page content remains the same. It still contains the same UI made for **/create_user_name** route instead of **/list** UI.

history.js Component

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history'
const history = createBrowserHistory()

export default history
```

Im using reducer. store component

```
import io from 'socket.io-client'
import history from '../Components/history'
// import axios from 'axios'
//connect to the server
const socket = io.connect('localhost:3030')
console.log(socket)

//listen for number of users
export const users = socket.on('users', users => {
  console.log(users)
  return users
})

export const setUser = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_NAME':
      console.log(action.name)
      const data = {
        name: action.name
      }

      //sent user using socket
      socket.emit('Create_name', data)
      console.log(history)
      history.push('/list') // I CALL THE HISTORY.PUSH HERE

      return state

    default:
      console.log('Default State')
      break
  }
}
```

Sorry if this question is asked before.

Comment: Can we see the function where your execute the history.push?  Should be like `props.history.push`

Comment: I imported ```createHistory``` from react history . Then executed ```history.push()```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.Pass the **history** to the Router:

```
import { Router } from 'react-router-dom'
import history from './history'
...
function App() {
  return (
    <Router history={history}>
      ...
    </Router>
  )
}
```

Make sure you import **Router** and not BrowserRouter

> As BrowserRouter uses its own history and does not accept any outer history property, we have to use Router instead of it.

2.Now whenever you want to use the history outside of a React component you first import it and then you use it.

```
import history from './history'
...
history.push('/list');
```

This way the router is aware of the changes made to the history.

When you are inside of a React component you directly use [useHistory](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Hooks/usehistory) hook

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you used HashRouter.
The code below will help you.

```
import createHistory from 'history/createHashHistory'
const history = createHistory()

history.push(URL_YOU_WANT)
```

Comment: I also did the same thing and executed the history.push(). I didn't use HashRouter.